# How to deploy winform c# application with database in same installation on another PC's?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, deployment, installation

I developed a c# windows form application in visual studio 2015 which is connected to sql server express 2014, application with simple read and write data to database which has only one table, and now I want to put both in same installation and deploy it on other PC's with OS Windows 10, so user can install application with one click setup, next, next, finish. How can I do it? I need step by step, because I read a lot of articles and do some of the examples and not one works. Is it better to use SQL Server Compact or SQLite, to use Visual Studio Installer or Advanced Installer, do I must write scripts or can do it with ssdt or give me any other suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Compact Edition, Database actually just a file (**.sdf**) which can be bundled with your window form application.

when you create the installation file, just **include** SQL compact file (**.sdf**)

So either *Visual Studio Installer* or *Advanced Installer* is your choice.

**You can refer to this question too 
[How to create single file setup in windows application in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910569/how-to-create-single-file-setup-in-windows-application-in-c)